# Breaking change of loading Vue? between electron 19.1.5 and electron 20.0.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron

I used Vue 2.6.14 in my electron app, calling it from main JavaScript script like this:

```
import Wookmark from 'wookmark/wookmark';
import Vue from 'vue'; // <-- HERE
import {Language} from './model/language';
import Header from '../vue/header.vue';
import VueContextMenu from "vue-context-menu";
import bsn from "bootstrap.native";
```

Before electron 19.1.5 it worked well, but after electron 20.0.0, this code does not worked.
The code stopped around `import Vue from 'vue';` with error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: module not found: ./maplist` (NOTE: `maplist` is the name of this script).

[image]

What is this breaking change between electron 19 and 20?
How can I avoid it?

Conditions:
electron: 19.1.5 and 20.0.0
Vue: 2.6.14
electron-builder: 23.6.0
vue-loader: 15.9.8
vue-template-compiler: 2.6.14
vue-context-menu: 2.0.6
I don't use any "vue-electron"-ish solutions.

======

Additional info:

With checking this [page](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable?page=3#20.0.0), I found workaround that adding `sandbox: false` setting in my main.js

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: appWidth,
    height: appHeight,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/api/preload.js'), // eslint-disable-line no-undef
      sandbox: false // <- This
    }
  });
```

But the defult value of `sandbox` is `true`, I believe it is by security reason, so I want to know how to call vue with default `sandbox` setting, to keep security.

Comment: Please post the result of `yarn why vue` (if using `yarn`) or `npm list --depth=0` (if using `npm` - not all of it, only the `vue` version). I an interested in the ***actual*** `vue` version installed, guessing your `package.json` points to a `^2.x` version.

Comment: ```
+-- vue-context-menu@2.0.6
+-- vue-loader@15.9.8
+-- vue-template-compiler@2.6.14
+-- vue@2.6.14
```
Is this OK?

Comment: Does it work with `nodeIntegration: true`?

Comment: Yes, I tried just now, it also worked.

Comment: There's your answer, then.

Comment: Do you mean, Vue 2 has node dependancy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249641/discussion-between-tao-and-kochizufan).